# KeyListener and Paint Not Working

Tags: java, swing, paint, runnable

I'm making a game and I'm trying to get the moving working. Here's what I have so far.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class ForgottenMain extends JFrame implements KeyListener,MouseListener{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4926251405849574401L;
    public static BufferedImage attic,flashlight,player;
    public static boolean up,down,left,right;
    public static int px,py;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{    
            player = ImageIO.read(new File("char.png"));
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        new ForgottenMain();


    }
    public ForgottenMain(){
        init();
    }
    public void init(){
        setSize(1200,800);
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Forgotten");

          java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if(up == true){
                        System.out.println("Increasing the coordinate");
                        py--;
                        repaint();

                    }
                    if(down == true){
                        py++;
                        repaint();
                    }
                    if(left == true){
                        px--;
                        repaint();
                    }
                    if(right == true){
                        px++;
                        repaint();
                    }

                }
            });


    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.drawImage(attic,0,0,this);
        g2.drawImage(player, px, py, this);
        g2.drawImage(flashlight, px, py, this);
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 87){
            up = true;
            System.out.println("Up = true");
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 83){
            down = true;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 65){
            left = true;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 68){
            right = true;
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 87){
            up = false;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 83){
            down = false;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 65){
            left = false;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 68){
            right = false;
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

The key listener is working, but I think I'm doing something wrong with the loop/invoke later thing. I've never used it before so could someone maybe explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use `javax.swing.Timer` instead of `invokeLater`. You should increment coordinates repeatedly. Also use panel instad of frame and override the method `paintComponent` instead of `paint`

Comment: @Sergiy Medvynskyy  I'm not very good at Java yet, can you maybe explain why to do these things?

Comment: how you want to implement your game without to understand Java and Swing? `invokeLater` is called only one time. But you need a pereodically job to update your frame/panel. So you need to use a [timer triggered job](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).